# Delete C# form object and display new objects when progress bar ends and changes background image

Tags: c#, forms

I am making a program that once a progress bar expires, it changes the background image, destroys the current form objects (like progress bar) and display new form objects. Explanation of the code is appreciated a lot. I am using Visual Studio 2017. Here's how the code looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Form_Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (progressBar1.Value < 100)
            {
                this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
            }

            else {
                timer1.Stop();
                Image myImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\user\source\repos\Form Application\Form Application\res\img1.png");
                this.BackgroundImage = myImage;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the [`visual-studio`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) tag wiki: "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio. Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question."

Comment: So what is the issue? You have not asked a question but just told us what you are doing.

Comment: That is not even a working timer.  You can just copy code from MSDN and get a working timer.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the background image of a form when a progress bar expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783972/changing-the-background-image-of-a-form-when-a-progress-bar-expires)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Form_Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //create new form object
        Form1 f = null;
        //This is the constructor of the form
        public Form1()
        {
            //intializecomponent is used to construct the design of a form
            InitializeComponent();
            //ser form1 object to this
            f=this;
            //it the method to start the timer
            this.timer1.Start();
        }
        //this is the event handler which is called when time of the timer is increased
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //check if progress bar value is less than 100
            if (progressBar1.Value < 100)
            {
                //increase the value of progress bar by 1
                this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
            }

            else {
                //stop the timer when progress bar value is 100
                timer1.Stop();
                //get the image from the path
                Image myImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\user\source\repos\Form Application\Form Application\res\img1.png");
                //set the image to the forms background here this represents the object of the form
                this.BackgroundImage = myImage;
                //create new form
                Form1 formobj = new Form1();
                //show new form
                formobj.show();
                //close current form
                f.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different than what was posted in the question?

Comment: I have done some modification to close the form and to create a new form its a recursive call.

Comment: I really didn't understand what u r trying to achieve by this code ! taking an object of the same form then assign it as a Form1 , then making an instance of the same form, then showing the instance, then close the main object ! what's going on here ?

Comment: "it changes the background image, destroys the current form objects (like progress bar) and display new form objects. "